# Spring Book use nested json object for RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a controller that I want to accept a custom object in it's request body.  But, the json data coming in is nested.  Is it possible to map the nested json object to a class?  Or, do I need to take the json object in as a string instead and use a json mapper (like Jackson)?  Here is an example of what I mean:

**json data being sent:**

```
{
   'function_call': 'create_book',
   'date_called': 1672753599223,
   'Book':{
      'id': 1,
      'title': "some title',
      'desc': 'some desc'
   }
}
```

**Book class:**

```
@Data
public class Book{
   public int id;
   public String title;
   public String desc;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping("/data-product")
@ResponseBody
public void createBook(@RequestBody Book book) {          
    System.out.print(book);        
}
```

Comment: What's a Spring Book, lol? ... hmmm.  maybe that was what you meant to type.  Is the "Book" in the subject correct or should that be "Boot"?

Answer (score -1):

the way to do so it's creating a new class to handle your JSON object, Spring need to know the strcucture of your JSON. Do it like so

Class Book:

```
@Data
public class Book {
   public int id;
   public String title;
   public String desc;
}
```

Creeate a Request class to hadle your JSON:

Reminder! attributes name has to have the same as your JSON request

```
@Data
public class BookRequest {

   public Book Book;

    /* You can set the other next tow attributes if you want
      public String function_call;
      public Long date_called;
    */
}
```

And then set your Book Request class as a parameter and youre be able to get only the data on Book obj in your JSON:

[image]

JSON request:

```
{
  "function_call": "create_book",
  "date_called": 1672753599223,
  "Book": {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Spring Book use nested json object for RequestBody",
  "desc": "Stackoverflow jason question"
 }
}
```